# tkinter show images of a database

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a dataset called "df_db" in which I have stored images in base64 format in a column called "Images". Now, I would like to use tkinter to scroll through the images one after the other. So far I have implemented a scrollbar and I use that value to extract a base64 string from my database which I then convert to an image and try to show in tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

def show_frame(val):
    #Covert from base64
    b64 = df_db["Images"][int(val)]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(b64)

    #Show image
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata)))
    panel = Label(root, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

root = Tk()

w1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=42, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=show_frame)
w1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So far it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to store a reference to your image somewhere, or it will immediately be garbage-collected - `panel.image = img` perhaps.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion, but it results in the pictures getting stacked onto each other. Actually, I always just want to show th e current image set by the value of w1.

Comment: Well, you'd need to get rid of the previous Label to avoid that - or have a single Label, created at the start, that you simply set the `image` option of whenever you change images.